# Semiconductors: LED

Tags: semiconductor-physics

My book mentions that, "the bandwidth of light emitted by an LED is $100$ angstrom to $500$ angstrom or in other words (but not exactly) monochromatic". What that supposed to mean?  Is that mean the range of wavelengths? if it is, visible light isn't from it. Then what it is? bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figures are for the bandwidth of the light output, or the range of wavelengths with significant power.

The light from an LED is not completely at a single wavelength.  You might have one type where the output is centered on 700nm.  But when measured, you find that significant output can be detected between 690nm and 710nm.  The bandwidth for this item would be 20nm (or 200 angstroms).